# body is not printing in mail which is send through java mail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have the below program which works perfect and send the mail through java mail api the only issue that i have with the below program is that in the mail body there is no text , but int he program below as you can see that i have entered the body text as  "Test Mail for mail body" , please advise what changes i need to do in my below program so that in the mail body i can get the text as also.

As advise by folks i have updated the code below,

```
public class abcMailTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String mailSmtpHost = "77.77.77.77";
            String mailSmtpPort = "4321" ;

             String mailTo = "avdg@abc.com";
            //String mailCc = "avdg@abc.com ";
            String mailFrom = "avdg@abc.com";
            String mailSubject = "sgdtetrtrr";
            String mailText = "Test Mail for mail body ";
            sendEmail(mailTo,  mailFrom, mailSubject, mailText, mailSmtpHost ,mailSmtpPort );
        }

        public static void sendEmail(String to,  String from, String subject, String text, String smtpHost , String mailSmtpPort) {
            try {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
                properties.put("mailSmtpPort", mailSmtpPort);

                //obtaining the session 
                Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
                emailSession.setDebug(true);


                //creating the message
                Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
                emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
                 Address[] cc = new Address[] {
                 new InternetAddress("avdg@abc.com"),
                 new InternetAddress("saxenasaral@gmail.com")};
                 emailMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, cc);
                 emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                 emailMessage.setSubject(subject);



                // Create the message part
                 BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                 messageBodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html");
                 messageBodyPart.setText(text);


                // Create a multipart message
                 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

              // Part two is attachment
                 MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                 String filename = "c:\\SettingupRulesin outlook2003.pdf";
                 DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                 attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                 attachPart.setFileName(filename);

                multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);

                 // Send the complete message parts
                 emailMessage.setContent(multipart);

            emailSession.setDebug(true);


                Transport.send(emailMessage);
            }    catch (AddressException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error may be that you are assigning
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
and then
    messageBodyPart = new MimeMultipart();
later, before you have added it to the emailMessage, so clearing out the message body text you added.

Comment: Thanks for the advise please also advise how can i overcome from this  in other words how should i modify my above code please

Comment: i have modified the code now please advise is it the approach that you were advising